# Undefined control sequence with \overbar

Tags: equations, amsmath

can anyone tell me why I get an "undefined control sequence" error with the following code please?

```
\documentclass[times]{fldauth}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \overbar{u_i}}{\partial x_i}=0
\label{eq1n1}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: do you want `\overline`?

Comment: or `\bar` but not `\overbar`

Comment: Or `\bar`? Or `\widebar` from `mathabx`?

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick responses! \bar seems to work - thanks! I had been trying overline as well, but that was producing a very long bar that looked odd. Thanks again and sorry for the beginner question!

Answer (score 2):

`\overbar` is wrong initially (I did not found `fldauth.cls`)

This shows the (incomplete) possibilities to use a `\overline` - like typesetting of a mathematical symbol

```
\documentclass{article} %[times]{fldauth}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}

%\begin{equation}
%\frac{\partial \overbar{u_i}}{\partial x_i}=0
%\label{eq1n1}
%\end{equation}

\begin{align}
  \dfrac{\partial \bar{u_i}}{\partial x_i} &=0 \\
  \dfrac{\partial \widebar{u_i}}{\partial x_i} &=0 \\
  \dfrac{\partial \overline{u_i}}{\partial x_i} &=0 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would not use the overlining for the full variable with index, only for the quantity...